Integrating chatgpt-api into Angular 15 project problem
I'd like to create a chatbot in my Angular 15 project, so I'm trying to integrate the chatgpt-api into my  project but I'm encountering errors.
After running npm install chatgpt-api the chatgpt-api version in my package.json is: "chatgpt-api": "^0.0.6",. When I tried to get a newer version running npm install chatgpt-api@latest --save it said it's up to date. And when a checked the available versions running npm info chatgpt-api and npm view chatgpt-api versions it still says I have the newest version.
Are there really no newer versions?
My code is:
import chatgpt from "chatgpt-api";

/*..in my class..*/

chat = new chatgpt("sk-...");

async answerMessage(){
      try {        
        let answer = await this.chat.sendPrompt("hello");
        console.log(answer.message);
      } catch(error){
        console.error("Something went wrong when answering", error);
      }
    }
  }


Errors encountered:
Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'zlib' in '....\Angular\web_shop\node_modules\chatgpt-api\dist'
BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.
If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
- add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "zlib": require.resolve("browserify-zlib") }'
- install 'browserify-zlib'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
resolve.fallback: { "zlib": false }
And similar errors for util, http, https, url, crypto, os, tty, assert and stream modules.
My project doesn't have a webpack.config.json file, so I tried creating a new file with the following content:
module.exports = {
    resolve: {
      fallback: { "url": require.resolve("url/"),
      "util": require.resolve("util/") }
    }
  };

I even tried to add to my package.json file:
"browser": {
    "zlib": false,
    "url": false,
    "crypto": false,
    "os": false,
    "tty": false,
    "http": false,
    "https": false,
    "assert": false,
    "stream": false
  }

But then I get this error:
Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined
74 util.js:109
Webpack 17
webpack_require
1403
webpack_require
2226
webpack_require
158
webpack_require
6747
webpack_require
4431
webpack_require
webpack_exec

O

webpackJsonpCallback

Can anyone provide guidance on how to properly configure webpack or suggest alternative solutions?
